# preg_match not returning the correct values?

Tags: php, preg-match

So to test my code I made it return "0" for false and "1" for true. Now, here are my tests for this code here.

```
echo input("title", "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf should be safe input");
echo input("title", "sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf should be safe input");
echo input("title", "Omg what's this should be safe input");
echo input("title", "<a href>This should not be safe input");
echo input("user", "This_should_be_safe");
```

And here's my code below

```
function input($type, $input) {
    global $config, $alert;
    if ($type == "user") {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $input))
            return "1";
        else
            return "0";
    } else if ($type == "safetitle") {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $input))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else if ($type == "title") {
        if (preg_match('/[^0-9a-z\s-\'!?#_]/i', $input))
            return "1";
        else
            return "0";
    } else if ($type == "body") {
        if (preg_match('/[^0-9a-z\s-\'!?#_]/i', $input))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This is only tested with the user & title type, but they're both returning these results in this exact order.

```
`00011`
```

I don't think I'm doing anything incorrectly as when I used this in Regexr it showed that it was correct (at least I think it did)

Comment: So what's the expected value? Because the input and output is correct as it is :)

Comment: Well it's suppose to return false if the characters in the string do not match the pattern... If you read the PHP code I have where it says this input should be valid and this shouldn't, thats my point I guess :P I don't know how to explain it better the "safe" input should be true and "not safe" input should be false.

Comment: So you wanted it to be `11101`, correct? Do include it in the question so we can help :)

Comment: Instead of regex use filter_var: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `title` block, you use this:

```
preg_match('/[^0-9a-z\s-\'!?#_]/i', $input)
```

This means, if I see anything that's NOT (`^`) `0-9`, `a-z`, `\s`, `-`, `'`, `!`, `?`, `#`, `_`, return `1`. In your first three inputs, you are giving pure `a-z`, hence it gives you `0`. Whereas in your fourth input, you are giving a `<` in the text, so it's giving a `1`. You simply just need to remove the negate `^` if you want to reverse the result.

---

In the `user` block, you use this:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $input)
```

This means, anything `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` in between the start & end, will return `1`. Hence this is correct.

I can't recommend a better solution because you didn't tell us what is your main goal here, and this piece of code looks like doing some sort of sanitation, that I wouldn't recommend to do like this because it simply doesn't cover them all.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. I did mess up majorly, I'm still new to preg_match and the expressions I copied were mainly copied from the "Community" section of Regexr, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

### I believe you have 3 problems with your regex where

`if ($type == "title") {...` and `if($type == "body") {..`

Your regex for both: `/[^0-9a-z\s-\'!?#_]/i`

1. First problem is the '^' is inside of the '[ ]' when it is inside that negates anything inside of the brackets so it is finding characters that **Don't** include those.
2. The second problem is that you should have a '^' in the beginning of expression and a '$' at the end. This means return true only if all characters match the requirements

   3. The third is small just remember to have a + sign just after the closing ']' to indicate if it finds one or more characters found in the brackets.

your final regex should look like `^/[0-9a-z\s\-\'!?#_]+$/i`